# Saving value of a field from one model to another model field

Tags: django

How can I save a field value of a model to another model field? Suppose Model A has a date field and Model B also has date field. B is linked with A. Date field of A has already some dates. Using date field of B we change some dates to other dates into Model B database. I want to save these new dates to the Model A date field so that when I filter dates of Model A all the dates shows.

Hope somebody suggests ways to do that.

Comment: Is your question about filtering or how to synchronize the fields? Filtering can be done much easier.

Comment: You can get full idea from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38939911/how-to-set-shifting-date-as-new-sitting-date-and-include-in-showing-sitting-date

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do so is with [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save). Add a post_save handler that manages the dates.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(pre_save, sender=B)
def model_pre_change(sender, **kwargs):
    # place your date magic here, "sender" is your model instance
```

Comment: Hi @schacki, could you give an example.